# How to calculate difference between two dates using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, datetime

I need to calculate the `datetime` difference using the node.js. I am using the `dateformat` package to get current datetime format. My code is below:

```
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var prev_date=2017-08-09T19:00:58+0530;
var now = new Date();
var current_date=dateFormat(now, "isoDateTime");
```

Here I have already the previous date and also the current `datetime` also. I need to calculate the difference between two dates in hour, minute and second separately.

Comment: Use `moment` instead of `dateformat`.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

Answer (score 12):

```
let firstDate = new Date("7/13/2016"),
    secondDate = new Date("09/15/2017"),
    timeDifference = Math.abs(secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime());

console.log(timeDifference);
alert(timeDifference)
```

If you want the number of days between the two dates...

```
let differentDays = Math.ceil(timeDifference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

console.log(differentDays);
alert(differentDays);
```

You could also use Moment.js https://momentjs.com/docs/

```
console.log(moment.utc(moment(firstDate,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(secondDate,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: Why do you need `Math.abs` when you are doing an operation which is guaranteed to return a positive value?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant With the hard coded dates, it's guaranteed, but as the OP is almost certainly not comparing two hard coded dates it much be necessary (depending on the use case).

Answer (score 9):

If you want to calculate day-difference between two dates you don't require any package. You can use simple JavaScript.

```
var date1 = new Date("08/09/2017");
var date2 = new Date("08/10/2017");
var diffDays = parseInt((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); //gives day difference 
//one_day means 1000*60*60*24
//one_hour means 1000*60*60
//one_minute means 1000*60
//one_second means 1000
console.log(diffDays)
```

Comment: Has pretty significant off-by-one errors due to rounding with floats. Hopefully nobody is using this in production.

Answer (score 2):

```
function date_diff(d1, d2, get_item)
{
var date1 = new Date(d1)
var date2 = new Date(d2)
var Difference_In_Time = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
switch (get_item) {
    case 'month':
        return Math.round(Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 30));
    case 'day':
        return Math.round(Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    case 'hour':
        return Math.round(Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600));
    case 'minute':
        return Math.round(Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 60));
    case 'second':
        return Math.round(Difference_In_Time / 1000);    
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! Would be nice with an explanation of your answer and not just code.

Comment: @softarn It is quite straightforward.  Here is an example: "date_diff(1636283000707, 1636282718929, "minute"); >> 5 [min]"

Answer (score -3):

```
var moment = require('moment');
diffDateAndTime(stratDate, endDate, startTime, endTime) {
 let nowDate = moment(Date.now()).format("YYYY-MM-DD"); 
 let nowTime = moment(Date.now()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
 let dateOfStart = moment(stratDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"); 
 let dateOfEnd =moment(endDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
 let timeOfStart = moment(Date.now()).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + " " + moment(startTime).format("HH:mm"); 
 let timeOfEnd = moment(Date.now()).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + " " + moment(endTime).format("HH:mm"); 
 let diffDate, diffTime;
 diffDate = (moment(dateOfStart).diff(nowDate) <= 0) && (moment(dateOfEnd).diff(nowDate) >= 0);
 if (moment(dateOfStart).diff(nowDate) === 0) {
   diffTime = (moment(timeOfStart).diff(nowTime) < 0) 
   diffDate = diffTime; 
 }
 if (moment(dateOfEnd).diff(nowDate) === 0) { 
   diffTime = moment(timeOfEnd).diff(nowTime) > 0 diffDate = diffTime;
 }
return diffDate; 
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).